Google Sheets query, calculate time
I have a query with the following columns C(date), D(start time), E(end time)
In the query I would like to find the lowest start time and the highest end time for each day and subtract the start time from the end time, so I get the hours between the two times.
I hope someone can help me get the formula to work.
=QUERY('Alt data'!A2:H;"SELECT C, max(E), min(D), max(E)-min(D)
WHERE H is not null
AND C >= date '"&TEXT(B19;"YYYY-MM-DD")&"' 
AND 
C <= date '"&TEXT(C19;"YYYY-MM-DD")&"'
And
B = '"&C32&"'

GROUP BY C
ORDER BY C desc
LABEL C 'Dato'
Label max(E)-min(D) 'Hours'
";0)


find the lowest start time and the highest end time for each day and subtract the start time from the end time This is ambiguous; would you please provide a more detailed definition as well as some sample data and expected outcomes. At present each of the answers works on a different assumption and it is not clear which is "correct".

In a query(), you can subtract one pure number from another, but cannot directly get the difference between two time values. To do that, convert start times and end times to pure values, then format the result as a duration, like this:
=let( 
  dates, filter(C2:C, isdate_strict(C2:C)), 
  durations, filter(E2:E - D2:D, isdate_strict(C2:C)), 
  query( 
    hstack(dates, durations), 
    "select Col1, max(Col2) 
     group by Col1 
     format max(Col2) '[h]:mm' ", 
    0 
  ) 
)

Alternatively, use filter(), like this:
=let( 
  dates, sort(unique(tocol(C2:C, 1))), 
  map(dates, lambda(d, let( 
    start, min(filter(D2:D, C2:C = d)), 
    end, max(filter(E2:E, C2:C = d)), 
    duration, end - start, 
    hstack( 
      to_date(d), 
      query(duration, "format Col1 '[h]:mm' ", 0) 
    ) 
  ))) 
)

See
let(),
unique(),
tocol(),
map(),
filter(),
hstack(),
to_date()
and
query().

Thank you very much for your post doubleunary
I want to add a delimiter between two dates for example, the first and the last of a specific month.
and then add a filter on column B on a specific name that comes from a cell.
Is there any chance you can help me with that?
Thank you very much

Ask only one question per post. Post a new question instead.

Yes, you are absolutely right, sorry for my ignorance  I'm trying to follow the instructions.

An alternative, using QUERY function;
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({C2:E,E2:E-D2:D},"Select Col1, Max(Col4) Where Col1 Is Not Null Group By Col1 Label Col1 'DATE', Max(Col4) 'MAX TIME' Format Max(Col4) 'HH:MM'"))

.

